# difficulty with naming dataframe using loop, rbind and list of dataframe names

Tags: r, loops

I am a new R programmer.  I am trying to use rbind to combine temporary data frames.  I need the names of each set of combined datasets to come from a list of data frames that a loop iterates through.

I can get the temporary files to combine properly, but it doesn't work if I use the data frame name from iterating through the name list.  I have searched and searched and also called a programmer friend, to no avail.  Thank you!!

```
#initialize empty data frames
sheet1 <- data.frame(County = character(), Winner = character())
sheet2 <- data.frame(County = character(), Winner = character())
sheet3 <- data.frame(County = character(), Winner = character())
sheet4 <- data.frame(County = character(), Winner = character())

#put empty data frames into a list
sheet_dfs <- c(sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4)

#pull information from different Excel sheets for each iteration (not shown here)
#and write to element of list of dataframes 
for (i in 1:3) {
  temp1 <- data.frame(c("Cobb","Clayton","Fulton"), c("Kemp","Abrams","Smith"))
  colnames(temp1) <- c("County","Winner")
  temp2 <- data.frame(c("Henry","Polk","Gwinnett"), c("Fuller","Parker","Newsome"))
  colnames(temp2) <- c("County","Winner")
  sheet_dfs[[i]] <- rbind(temp1,temp2)}

sheet1 #expecting a data frame with names, what am I doing wrong?
sheet2 #expecting a data frame with names, what am I doing wrong?
sheet3 #expecting a data frame with names, what am I doing wrong?

test <- rbind(temp1,temp2)
test #this is exactly the output I need for my dataframes sheet1,sheet2,sheet3. 
returns:
County  Winner
1     Cobb    Kemp
2  Clayton  Abrams
3   Fulton   Smith
4    Henry  Fuller
5     Polk  Parker
6 Gwinnett Newsome
```

Comment: Once objects are saved to a list their original sources are not connected and remain as separate objects. The *sheets* data frames are never reassigned values so they remain empty.

Comment: You've only modified the contents of `sheet_dfs` but not `sheet1`, `sheet2`, or `sheet3`. You'll notice that `names(sheet_dfs)` doesn't even relate back to `sheet1`...

Comment: Is there a way to name these dataframes that I am creating using the "i" from the loop?

Comment: Probably want: `sheets_df["sheet1"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a proper named list. Your initial list assignment just creates a vector via `c`. Furthermore, you need to access the list elements properly via `[[` or name. See below modification of your code.

```
# set up named list programmatically
sheet_names = paste0("sheet", 1:4)
sheet_dfs = setNames(vector(length = length(sheet_names), mode = "list"), sheet_names)
# you can also create a named list as follows, which is, however, less programmatically
# sheet_dfs = list("sheet1" = sheet1, "sheet2" = sheet2, ...)

# your temp assignments...
#pull information from different Excel sheets for each iteration (not shown here)
#and write to element of list of dataframes 
for (i in 1:3) {
  temp1 <- data.frame(County = c("Cobb","Clayton","Fulton"), Winner = c("Kemp","Abrams","Smith"))
  temp2 <- data.frame(County = c("Henry","Polk","Gwinnett"), Winner = c("Fuller","Parker","Newsome"))
  sheet_dfs[[i]] <- rbind(temp1,temp2)
}

# access the list via name or index
sheet_dfs[[1]]
sheet_dfs["sheet1"]
```